# itext causing application to crash

Tags: itext

Sadly this is only happening on users machines, and not on my development machine.

The event log shows the following:
[image]

I've checked the version of .Net that is installed on the users machine and it matches what I have installed on my machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are distributing an AGPL library to end users. Are you a customer of iText Group? Also: how can we answer if you're not telling us which version of iTextSharp you're using? You have an initialization error in the constructor, but which version of `PdfReader` should we look at *if* we want to help you?

Comment: The problem occurs in the PdfReader constructor. There may be something special about the pdf it is constructed for. Is it from the file system? In that case: does the file exist? Does it have special permissions? Or is it constructed some other way? Describe,please,and supply code and sample pdf to reproduce the issue with.